# Looping problem with defauldict in Django templates

Tags: python, django

On my Django , i used defauldict on my views, and to give a structure I put this code in my template , but it s not working nothing happen in my output

What i need to change please ?
I want to see in my web page something like this :

```
.List in the file :
value
value1
value3
...

.List not in the file :
value
value 
value...
```

.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Dashboard Result</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Convert the defaultdict to a regular dict? `dict(results)`

Comment: where in my views?

Comment: Wherever you think is appropriate, I would do it either when you call `render` or in the return of `results1` - `return dict(results_list), output_df.to_html()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key and value are the key/value pairs of the defaultdict. Change

```
{% for key, value in results.items %}
         {{ item.key }}
         {{ item.value}}
{% endfor %}
```

to

```
{% for key, value in results.items %}
         {{ key }}
         {{ value}}
{% endfor %}
```

and since value is a list you might want

```
{% for key, value in results.items %}
         {{ key }}
         {% for elem in value %}
              {{ elem }}
         {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thank you so much !!!!!! it s exactly this!!!!